# Why is it said not to eat before worshiping God?

Tags: rituals, temple, tradition, customs

Even for worshipping god everyday in the morning, it is said to have breakfast only after worshipping god. Or it can be said in other way that if one worships god, he or she has to complete pooja first and then, has to eat.

And, i also heard from one of my friends that one have to take bath again to go to a temple even though he had it in the morning. :p

Is it correct? If so, What could be the reason?

Comment: I heard from one of my friends that one have to wear makeup again to go to a party even though she had it in the morning :p

Answer (score 4):

[Bhagavad Gita 3.13](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/13)

> यज्ञशिष्टाशिन: सन्तो मुच्यन्ते सर्वकिल्बिषै: |
> भुञ्जते ते त्वघं पापा ये पचन्त्यात्मकारणात् ||
>
> yajna-shishtashinah santo muchyante sarva-kilbishaih
> bhunjate te tvagham papa ye pachantyatma-karanat
>
> The spiritually-minded, who eat food that is first offered in sacrifice, are released from all kinds of sin.
> Others, who cook food for their own enjoyment, verily eat only sin.

Commentary :
Every food inevitably involves violence.
Obviously non-vegetarian food eaters enjoy the flesh of a murdered animal that suffered in great fear and pain.
But even vegetarian food causes some pain to plants, animals that get crushed under tractor, insects/microbes that get drowned or burned while cooking etc.

To avoid this sin, there are 2 ways :

1. Don't eat anything. This method is followed by Jain monks who simply give up their body and die.
2. Offer food as sacrifice (yagna, puja) to Bhagavan, who pardons the sin. This method is followed by almost every religion/sect - Brahmins (Pariseshan), Hindus (Nivedan/Prasad), Muslims (bismillah), Christians (grace).

There are varying levels in-between, where some only eat **Uncha**-Vritthi (only gathering grains and fruits that have automatically fallen on ground), **Kapota**-Vritthi (only buying/saving food for 1 day, not caring about tomorrow), **Ajagara**-Vritthi (only eating whatever falls on their lap)

**Pancha-Maha-Yagna** or 5 great sacrifices are ordained as part of daily life for a Gruhastha (householder), in order to absolve oneself of sin that occurs in 5 places during daily life (cooking, cutting, sweeping, storing, one more i forget) :

**Brahma** yagna (to Bhagavan & Rishis)
**Deva** Yagna (to devas)
**Pitru** Yagna (to ancestors)
**Manushya** Yagna (to relatives)
**Bhuta** Yagna (to animals)

[image]

Comment: Btw, Have you changed the user name from "ram" to "mar"? Looks reversed!

Comment: @Pandya - yep, cos i'm complete opposite of ram.

Comment: Ok. What does "ram" here refer to? Lord Ram?

Comment: @Pandya - yeah.

Comment: Interesting! What makes you opposite of Ram?

Comment: @Pandya - no gunas. rather, mainly bad gunas, but posing as good. that is worst offense according to Rama - being dishonest/hypocritical (Anarjavam) - sinning in secret but preaching in public.

Comment: @mar Sir knowing people like thy, makes me feel exalted. It's hard to accept own's vices, this is true u r spiritually uplifted. Hope, Bhagwati blesses downtrodden souls like us with your margdarshan.